# How to open up a tcp server compatible with tcpgoon

Tags: tcp, port

I have `tcpgoon` installed on one computer, provided that there is a direct VLAN connection, how do I create a TCP server on my second computer?

Comment: You should show what you've already tried and/or researched. See [ask].

Answer (score 0):

You can use any TCP server as a target, including HTTP servers (apache, nginx...), SMTP (sendmail, postfix...), servlet-containers (tomcat), application servers... but be careful, as tcpgoon can be used as an stress-test tool (its actual objective is to measure the maximum connections in parallel your servers effectively supports), so think twice before targeting a production server.